# How to sort QList<MyClass*> using Qt library (maybe qSort())?

Tags: c++, qt, sorting

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    int a;
    bool operator<(const MyClass other) const {
        return a<other.a;
    }
    ....
};
....
QList<MyClass*> list;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make your own comparator, that will work with pointers and then use qSort: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qtalgorithms.html#qSort-3

Comment: qSort is obsolete as per the docs, so std::sort should be used.

Comment: how to use std::sort with my class which is derived from QObject? clang says no matching function for call to 'swap', and this as far as understood is because my class doesn't have move constructor. But it is basically a QObject, it isn't suppose to has one I believe.

Answer (score 15):

In C++11 you can also use a lambda like this:

```
QList<const Item*> l;
qSort(l.begin(), l.end(), 
      [](const Item* a, const Item* b) -> bool { return a->Name() < b->Name(); });
```

Comment: This solution is simple, clear and actually works. Others give cryptic error messages.

Answer (score 13):

A general solution to the problem would be to make a generic less-than function object that simply forwards to the pointed-to-type's less-than operator. Something like:

```
template <typename T>
struct PtrLess // public std::binary_function<bool, const T*, const T*>
{     
  bool operator()(const T* a, const T* b) const     
  {
    // may want to check that the pointers aren't zero...
    return *a < *b;
  } 
};
```

You could then do:

```
qSort(list.begin(), list.end(), PtrLess<MyClass>());
```